# Edit Oracle Path on Ubuntu Virtual Machine

Tags: bash, oracle-database

I have two virtual machines ubuntu 14.04 LTS, one is a server when I installed oracle 11g express, and the other is a simple client. My goal is to run an sql query remotely from the client machine. So I prepared the query and I sent it to the server. But in the following of the script and after the establishment of the connection to the server, sqlplus dosen't work. And it shows me the following error:

```
Sqlplus: Command not found
```

The problem is how can edit the path.

in the end of the file `.bashrc` i have:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe 
export ORACLE_SID=XE export NLS_LANG=$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh` 
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and when i run the command `find /u01 -name sqlplus` i have this result:

```
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/sqlplus
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus
```

How can i execute this remote query?

Comment: Shouldn't be the command `sqlplus`, your error shows you issued it like `Sqlplus`

Comment: And have you logout then login and try again?

Comment: i edit the path and i restart the virtual machine but i don't have any things